# Change woocommerce products weight varation based its product category or tags?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

We are trying to automate our workflow a lil. Editing variations in WooCommerce can be tough. All our products fall into 5 categories based on how much "product" someone is trying to buy. Fortunately depending on the specific categories the weight of the product in that category should be the same.

So instead of updating 1000+ variations and checking to make sure all the weights (for shipping purposes) are set up correctly I thought i may be able to find a function that bases the weight of a products (including all that products variations) based on that products category or even based on a specific tag would work. *since u can add product tags*

Is there a solution already for this? Do u know of one? I was having troubling finding anyone trying to do something similar.

For example purposes: If we were selling socks. And each style of stock was a different color. Every sock product including the color variation that exist in the sock category would have the same weight of 200grams

Thanks for any help!